# Sending UPI intent string through SMS does not open UPI apps

Tags: android, sms, upi

When sending a UPI intent string through SMS, its not getting recognized as a link that can be clicked on. The intent string that I am sending looks like : upi://pay?pa=testuat@icici&pn=test&tr=EZV2021111610485300031599&am=1.00&cu=INR&mc=5411

I have tested it on a Samsung galaxy phone and a Oneplus, but the UPI intent string just comes up as plain text. If send through Slack, Slack recognizes it as a clickable (like a hyperlink) text and on clicking on it, it shows a list of supported UPI apps.

Can anyone help me understand how to get phones to recognize the UPI string as an intent string to open UPI supported apps ?

Comment: i think calling deep link in sms is not possble. try to tinyurl or other tiny url service. then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
Phonepe://upi/pay?pa=testuat@icici&pn=test&tr=EZV2021111610485300031599&am=1.00&cu=INR&mc=5411
```

Replace **Phonepe** with Any UPI Apps Name like **Paytm** **gpay** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Though its been time since the question was asked, UPI deep link not being recognized is not the "Link" fault, but the SMS app's fault.
The SMS itself is a very long packet received by the phone from which the phone extracts the payload "Message" and displays it to you. The SMS bubble rendered on the phone is simply a text holder which not always is given full capability by the Phone OS.

Explanation: Go to your file explorer, and rename a file as "example.com"; Does that filename turn into a link? NO, because the filename area is not treated to identify links.

The solution to your Problem:

Create a short link to your domain, or use other services like [bit.ly](https://bitly.com), etc. and once the user teacher to the browser, the moment your short link is directed to the payload (UPI intent Deeplink), the browser will redirect you to your default UPI app.

SMS-> Deeplink
change it to
SMS-> ShortLink -> Deeplink